# CSS selector for empty or whitespace

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

We have a selector `:empty` that can match an element when it is **completely empty**:

```
<p></p>
```

But I have a condition where it might be empty, or it might contain line breaks or blank spaces:

```
<p>    </p>
```

I found a solution for Firefox, `:-moz-only-whitespace`:

```css
:empty { width: 300px; height: 15px; background: blue; }
:-moz-only-whitespace { width: 300px; height: 15px; background: orange; }
```

```html
<p></p>
<p>    </p>
<p>This is paragraph three.</p>
```

Is there a similar solution for other browsers?

PS: [In JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzax9qj1/)

Comment: Can you provide a code example on JSFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fzax9qj1/

Comment: You tagged this with jQuery - you can add your own empty-check predicate if that would serve your purpose.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a pure CSS solution yet: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/b/blank/

Comment: At the moment, there isn't one that I can find `:blank` is part of [**CSS Level 4 Selectors**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#the-blank-pseudo) but still has not been implemented AFAIK.

Comment: `:-moz-only-whitespace{}` is the Mozilla's implementation of `:blank` before it is released in CSS4.

Comment: Yep, but wanted same for chrome, without javascript if possible.

Comment: Then you are SOL I'm afraid, there isn't one.

Comment: I guess the real question is **why** are you trying to style empty (or blank) elements? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @Paulie .. The data is coming from php backend, and in certain cases instead of blank in table column, it is sending the content with white-spaces, and will be cumbersome to get to people to change the whole format to send the table columns without spaces in those scenarios. So, was trying to handle this from css.

Comment: I still don't get what you need it for. Have you looked at the CSS property `white-space` though? I think you can merge multiple white spaces into one and vice versa

Comment: "The data is coming from php backend, and in certain cases instead of blank in table column, it is sending the content with white-spaces" Seems the correct approach would be to fix this issue in the backend

Comment: @Pointy: Something tells me the tags were a mistake. I see no reason to tag the question with JS/jQuery if they're specifically looking for a pure CSS solution only.

Comment: @Pointy ... Yep! But, might be someone with jquery knowledge would crack this eazily. Scope of knowledgable persons answering increase.

Comment: You should not add irrelevant tags to your question for that purpose. That is not an appropriate use of tags.

Comment: @Peterson well if you really want to solve the issue purely with CSS, then a jQuery solution does no good unfortunately.

Comment: Yep ..... ;/. Will take that to account !

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Lots of people missing the point of this question, which I've addressed in the following exposition, but for those just looking for the answer, I'm mirroring the last paragraph here:

> [Selectors 4 now redefines](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-empty-pseudo) `:empty` to include elements that contain only whitespace. This was originally proposed as a separate pseudo-class `:blank` but was recently retconned into `:empty` after it was determined that it was safe to do so without too many sites depending on the original behavior. Browsers will need to update their implementations of `:empty` in order to conform to Selectors 4. If you need to support older browsers, you will have to go through the hassle of marking elements containing only whitespace or pruning the whitespace before or after the fact.

---

While the question depicts a `<p>` element containing a handful of regular space characters, which seems like an oversight, it is far more common to see markup where elements contain only whitespace in the form of indentation and blank lines, such as:

```
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item">
    <div>
      <!-- Some complex structure of elements -->
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
  </li> <!-- Empty, except for a single line break and
             indentation preceding the end tag -->
</ul>
```

Some elements, like `<li>` in the above example as well as `<p>`, have optional end tags, which can cause unintended side effects in DOM processing as well in the presence of inter-element whitespace. For example, the following two `<ul>` elements don't produce equivalent node trees, in particular the first one does not result in a `li:empty` in Selectors level 3:

```css
li:empty::before { content: '(empty)'; font-style: italic; color: #999; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Given that [HTML considers inter-element whitespace to be transparent by design](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#inter-element-whitespace), it's not unreasonable to want to target such elements with CSS without having to resort to modifying the HTML or the application generating it (especially if you end up having to implement and test a special case just to do so). To that end, [Selectors 4 now redefines](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-empty-pseudo) `:empty` to include elements that contain only whitespace. This was originally proposed as a separate pseudo-class `:blank` but was recently retconned into `:empty` after it was determined that it was safe to do so without too many sites depending on the original behavior. Browsers will need to update their implementations of `:empty` in order to conform to Selectors 4. If you need to support older browsers, you will have to go through the hassle of marking elements containing only whitespace or pruning the whitespace before or after the fact.

Comment: IMHO this needs a brief answer, regardless of the explanation. TL;DR or what have you.

Comment: `:blank` no longer works as described here. Now it refers to inputs and their value. https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#changes-2018-02

Comment: @Kevin Beal: Thanks, I've updated my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: @Carles Alcolea: I've added a summary to the top of the answer. I mostly posted this explanation out of frustration from seeing so many people in the comments missing the point of the question.

Comment: `:empty` is not working for me on a `<dd>  </dd>` item filled with whitespace, in Firefox 87 on Ubuntu 20. But the `-moz-...` one does.

Comment: I kind of wish they went one step further and made the pseudo-element take effect if there was no visible content inside (eg. if everything was display: none then it would be considered empty).

Comment: **Important:** Despite this answer being nearly 7 years old `:empty` even in the latest Chrome still has the old behavior whereby you must remove all whitespace to be considered `:empty`. Comments are allowable but no whitespace.

Comment: The point that @Simon_Weaver has made is still valid today with Chrome 106, so almost a year later `:empty` still does not match if an element contains whitespace. So the css rule `p:empty` does still not match with `<p>   </p>`

Comment: Still not working on Firefox 112.0 January 2024. Sigh.

Comment: If your problem is Django dynamically generating nothing inside a wrapper you want to target with `display: none;` if `:empty`, look up the `{% spaceless %}` tag which deletes whitespace at source

Answer (score 5):

@BoltClock provided a fantastic answer to this question, showing that this (currently, that is, working with CSS Specification 3) cannot be achieved by CSS alone.

@BoltClock mentioned that elements that are **truly** empty (which is a weird definition as explained) can be targeted by using the pseudo selector `:empty`. This pseudo selector is only available in CSS 3 and WILL NOT select elements that have only whitespace as content.

@BoltClock stated that the only way to clean up elements that have only whitespace as content is to fix the HTML, but that is not entirely correct. This can also be achieved through the implementation of Javascript.

**KEEP IN MIND!** The Javascript that I am offering to solve this issue may take a very long time to execute, so the best method is to clean up the raw HTML instead if possible. If that is not possible, then this may work as a solution, as long as you do not have too extensive of a DOM tree.

I'll walk through the steps of how to write the script yourself...

**First of all**, launch everything after page load.

This should be pretty obvious. You need to make sure that the DOM has fully loaded before running your script. Add an `event listener` for page load:

```
window.addEventListener("load", cleanUpMyDOM);
```

...and, of course, before that, create a `function` called `cleanUpMyDOM`. We will write the rest of our logic within this function.

**Second**, gather the elements that we are checking.

In our example we are going to check the entire DOM, but this is where our script can get VERY extensive and may make your page unresponsive. You may want to limit the amount of nodes you are iterating over.

We can grab the nodes in question by using the `document.querySelectorAll`. What's nice about this function is that it will level out the DOM tree and we won't have to recurse the children of each node.

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("*");
```

As I said earlier, this code will grab EVERY DOM node, and that is probably NOT a good idea.

For example, I am working with WordPress, and some of the internal pages have some junk in them. Luckily, they are all `p` elements that are children of a `div.body` element, so I can change my selector to `document.querySelectorAll("div.body p")`, which will select only `p` elements that are children of my `div.body` element recursively. This will greatly optimize my script.

**Third**, iterate the nodes and find the empty ones.

We'll create a loop for the `nodes` array and check each node in it. We will then have to check to see if the node is empty. If it is empty, we'll apply a class to it called `blank`.

*I'm just shooting from the hip here, so if you notice a mistake in this code, please let me know.*

```
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    nodes[i].innerHTML = nodes[i].innerHTML.trim();
    if(!nodes[i].innerHTML)
        nodes[i].className += " blank";
}
```

I am sure that there is a cleaner way to write the loop above, but this should get the job done.

**Lastly**, all you need to do is target the blank elements with your CSS.

Add this rule to your stylesheet:

```
.blank {
    display:none;
}
```

And there you have it! All of your "blank" nodes have been hidden.

For those who just want to jump ahead, here is the finished script:

```
function cleanUpMyDOM(){
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("*");
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        nodes[i].innerHTML = nodes[i].innerHTML.trim();
        if(!nodes[i].innerHTML)
            nodes[i].className += " blank";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", cleanUpMyDOM);
```

Once again, if you notice any issues with my code, please let me know in the comments below.

Hope this helps!

**P.S.** Many people may be wondering why you would want to do this, as it does feel like bad practice. I would avoid doing this, but I am in a situation where I am starting to consider it. The content of the pages on my site are created through a WYSIWYG editor. This content is created and modified constantly by the marketing team and I get pretty overwhelmed handling the support for their slip-ups. Its not my job to fix WordPress's WYSIWYG editor (nor would I ever want to), but I could write a very simple script that can handle some of the work for me. That definitely seems like the better answer to me, besides training the support team on managing their whitespace when making edits.

Comment: Rewriting the `innerHTML` is bad. You will remove all internal data like event listeners, checkedness, custom properties, etc. The proper way would be iterating all text nodes at DOMContentLoaded, and remove the ones which only contain whitespace. Then `:empty` will work.

Comment: Good point @Oriol. As I said, this isn't the best approach. I should edit my answer to more specifically target text nodes.

Comment: Instead of rewriting `innerHTML` can't you just `if(!nodes[i].innerHTML.trim()) nodes[i].className += " blank";`?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at the exact link: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/Overview.bs#the-empty-pseudo

And TL;DR:

> Note: In Level 2 and Level 3 of Selectors, '':empty'' did not match
> elements that contained only white space. This was changed so that
> that-- given white space is largely collapsible in HTML and is
> therefore used for source code formatting, and especially because
> elements with omitted end tags are likely to absorb such white space
> into their DOM text contents-- elements which authors perceive of as
> empty can be selected by this selector, as they expect.

And `:empty` will consider spaces as empty from v4 onwards:

> content nodes (such as [[DOM]] text nodes, and entity references) whose data has a non-zero length must be considered as affecting emptiness; comments, processing instructions, and other nodes must not affect whether an element is considered empty or not.