# CSS selector for element without child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style a div element without child element such as below:

```
<div class="ps_box-group eopcColumnGroup">
    <span>hello</span>
</div>
<div class="ps_box-group eopcColumnGroup">

</div>
```

As you can see, there are multiple `<div>` elements with eopcColumnGroup class, the 1st div has a child span element, the 2nd div has no child element, but its text is not empty, the content is a bunch of [space] characters:

```
<div class="ps_box-group eopcColumnGroup">
[space][space][space][space]   
</div>
```

I'm using [space] to denote space characters.

What I need is I only want to write special styles for the 2nd div which has no child element, I tried pseudo-class empty like this:

```
div.eopcColumnGroup:empty {
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

But it does not work, because those space characters are not considered empty.

I'm confined to use standard CSS to do this, so how do I write the selector to only select the 2nd div?

Thanks for any tips, suggestions.

Comment: You cannot select parent based on a child. That's not something that's possible with pure css.

Comment: even more relevant duplicate (original) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382881/css-selector-for-empty-or-whitespace

Comment: Thanks, guess I will have to wait for :blank pseudo-class in CSS4. Surprised to find out there is no such support in CSS3.

Comment: @JackJoe may be you  will like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/7vag3dg4/2/

Comment: Thanks @Leothelion for the tip

Comment: @cobe24 your welcome