# CSS change class when div is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've managed to make sure my editable DIV is underlined red when I load my page. Then when I enter text, it becomes white. So far, so good. When I clear the field though, either with a function or just simply deleting it (Backspace/delete), it remains white. How to I get it back to understanding that it's empty, and changing the class back once more when the text has been cleared?

CSS:

```css
#Control1, #Control2, #Control3 {
background-image:url('img/underline_red.png');
}

#Control1:not([value=""]), #Control2:not([value=""]), #Control3:not([value=""])  {
background-image:url('img/underline.png');
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div contentEditable=true id="Control1" spellcheck="false" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="">
</div>

<br>

<div contentEditable=true id="Control2" spellcheck="false" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="">
</div>


<br>

<div contentEditable=true id="Control3" spellcheck="false" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="">
</div>


<br>

<div id="border">
<div contentEditable=true id="note" spellcheck="false" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="">
</div>
</div>


<br>


<button class="button"  onclick="clearControl1('Control1'), clearControl2('Control2'), clearControl3('Control3'), clearNote('note')"/>Clear</button>
```

Javascript:

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
function clearNote(note)
{
    document.getElementById(note).innerHTML = "";
}
function clearControl1(Control1)
{
    document.getElementById(Control1).innerHTML = "";
}
function clearControl2(Control2)
{
    document.getElementById(Control2).innerHTML = "";
}
function clearControl3(Control3)
{
    document.getElementById(Control3).innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: why are you using a div instead of a textarea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector for empty or whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382881/css-selector-for-empty-or-whitespace)

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
div:empty {
   some stuff like color
}
```

Detaild information on Browser-Support here, where this snippet is from

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/

in general, there are some css selectors doing help you react on advanced stuff like "the first" or "every second" etc..